# xml schema issues

Tags: xml, xsd

Can anyone spot the problem here? I've been staring at this thing for ages:

```
<xs:complexType name="stylesType">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="style" type="styleType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

 <xs:complexType name="tdType">
<xs:sequence>
    <element name="styles" type="stylesType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="tdvalue" type="tdValueType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="resource" type="iterableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    <element name="iterable" type="iterableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string"/> 
<xs:attribute name="forceposition" type="xs:string"/> 
<xs:attribute name="dragorientation" type="xs:string"/> 
<xs:attribute name="dragcount" type="xs:string"/> 
<xs:attribute name="dragtolabel" type="xs:string"/> 
</xs:complexType>
```

The error is on the line starting with `<element name="styles"...` but acts up on the first element of that containing sequence no matter the order the contents.

Comment: Asking us to solve the problem by staring at the code, without telling us what the error message is, suggests you have an odd way of going about diagnosing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to qualify `element` with namespace prefix like `xs:element`. So all element definitions like below

```
 <element name="...
```

will have to change to

```
 <xs:element name="...
```